# Check cell value compared to range using App Script

Tags: google-sheets

I have column A with data that I want to compare to column I. If A is in I, then I want to return what I have listed in Cell I1.

Cell A2 = Test.
Column I = Test, Run, Pass, Jump

If A2 = Column I Return "True"

This is what I have tried and it returns empty.
In cell B2 I am using '=TRYTHIS(A2)'

```
function TRYTHIS(one) {
  const [description] = one[0]
  
  if(description.includes(toString("Category!I2:I")))
  return "Category!I1"
}
```

There are no errors but it returns empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code. I added an extra line to return something when there's no match, but you can delete it or change its value:

```
function tryThis(one) {
  const description = one
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const colI = sheet.getRange("I:I").getValues().map(function (n){return n[0]})
  if(colI.indexOf(description) != -1){return sheet.getRange("I1").getValue()}
  else{return "Not found"}
}
```

It returns this when applied:

[image]

You could also do this with a formula:

```
=IF(IFNA(XMATCH(A1,I:I)),$I$1,"Not found")
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate both answers very much. I am mainly playing around with App script trying to remember what little JS I leered about 10 years ago. lol  It works just as I hoped it would!